# Javascript saying object value is undefined. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I'm trying to display the value of an object within an array of GitHub repositories (retrieved from a parsed JSON) in my React app but I'm getting an error that the browser can't read property *`key`* of undefined.

I'm able to console.log the JSON data and the objects within it but if I try to log the values within those objects, I get the error.

```
const App = () => {
const [repoList, setRepoList] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://example.com/api")
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => setRepoList(data));
});

return (
    <div>{repoList[0].id}</div>
)
```

}

If I put `JSON.stringify(repoList)` within the div element, it shows the data.

If I put `JSON.stringify(repoList[0])` within the div element, it also shows the data.

But if I put something like `repoList[0].id` nothing appears. This happens with each key listed. And I can confirm that the key is there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this - `<div>{repoList && repoList[0].id}</div>`

Comment: @ravibagul91 this will not work, he has intantiated the `repoList` with an empty object

Comment: Tried that but it didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
const [repoList, setRepoList] = useState([]); // Change to array not object.

...

return repoList.length ?
  (<React.Fragment>{repoList[0].id}</React.Fragment>) 
  : (<span>Loading ....</span>)
```

If your `div` does not have styles, better user `Fragment`, it result in better performance.

Comment: This did it for me! Thanks

Comment: you dont always want to use a fragment for something that doesn't have styles... that is a misleading statement. `<React.Fragment>Loading ....</React.Fragment>` I'd argue that having random strings in your html is more confusing and breaks HTML semantics than rather putting a `span` around the text.

Comment: @JohnRuddell, I agree, it was more of answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling async functions to populate the repo list. The first time the return tries to use `repoList[0].id`, there is no `repoList[0]`. You may want to initialize repoList to a non-error-ing dummy object when you set it up with `useState({})`

Comment: I see, thanks. I tried Morlo's suggestion below which I believe takes this into account and it works for me. Thanks